# jhipster 4.0 microservice : eureka password error

Tags: jhipster

I'm creating a new microservices project.

I'm using JHipster 4.0.3 and, according this issue [https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4905] Eureka password is define by `jhipster.registry.password`

So, in `application-dev.yml` Eureka configuration is, by default :

`eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/`

in the file `bootstrap-dev.yml` the password definition is look good:

`jhipster:
    registry:
        password: admin`

When I launch my gateway (or microservice) I've got this error message

> 2017-02-17 10:32:12.794 ERROR 2064 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
>
> at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
>
> at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.resource(Client.java:434)
>
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:187)

Work fine when I change my Eureka configuration in `application-dev.yml` to : 
`defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/`

**My configuration**

- JHipster version : 4.0.3
- Project : microservices
- Registry version : 2.5.8
- OS : Windows 7 64bits
- Launch from IDE Intellj

Thanks

Comment: mvn or gradle? take a look at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5240, it might be your issue, too

Comment: mvn. Not exactly the same issue but you right it's more an issue than a question

Comment: issue open : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5260